# Zybooks 5.7 Challenge

Tags: c

Write a loop that sets each array element to the sum of itself and the next element, except for the last element which stays the same. Be careful not to index beyond the last element.

Ex:
Initial scores:        10, 20, 30, 40
Scores after the loop: 30, 50, 70, 40

The first element is 30 or 10 + 20, the second element is 50 or 20 + 30, and the third element is 70 or 30 + 40. The last element remains the same.

I got my code to work but the part I find tricky is the "last element must remain the same". I used a temporary variable named "temp" to store the value at the start of the loop and then add it back after the loop. But I am sure there's a better way!

```html
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   const int SCORES_SIZE = 4;
   int bonusScores[SCORES_SIZE];
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i) {
      scanf("%d", &(bonusScores[i]));
   }
   
   int temp;
   for ( i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i) {
      
      temp = bonusScores [SCORES_SIZE - 1];
      bonusScores [i] = bonusScores [i] + bonusScores[i+1];
   }
   
   bonusScores[SCORES_SIZE - 1] = temp;

   for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i) {
      printf("%d ", bonusScores[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it works it works. What is your question? What do you want to improve? I.e. define "better", maybe by referring to one of the choices offered by the tag info wiki on "optimisation".  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/optimization/info Note that asking for a code review is off-topic on StackOverflow, though there is a sibling community for that.

Comment: Why is it tagged as C++? It seems to me to be C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is storing in the last element of your array a number that it is the sum of `bonusScores[SCORES_SIZE - 1]` and some value (on which you do not have any control) at `bonusScores[SCORES_SIZE]`. You overcome this problem by using the `temp` variable, but there is a simple solution to avoid using `temp`: do not loop on the entire array, just stop *before* the last element.

In this way you do not need the `temp` variable. Indeed,

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {

    const int SCORES_SIZE = 4;
    int bonusScores[SCORES_SIZE];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i) 
        scanf("%d", &(bonusScores[i]));
   
    printf("New vector \n");
    for ( i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE-1; ++i) {
        bonusScores [i] = bonusScores [i] + bonusScores[i+1];
        printf("%d \n", bonusScores[i]);
    }
    printf("%d \n", bonusScores[SCORES_SIZE-1]);
    return 0;
}
```

A further improvement could be to print the new values just after computed them, without any further loops.